# How to replace curly quotation marks in a string using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, replace

I am trying to replace curly quotes:

```
str = '“I don’t know what you mean by ‘glory,’ ” Alice said.';
```

Using:

```
str.replace(/['"]/g,'');
```

Why it does not work? How can I do this?

Answer (score 85):

You might have to (or prefer to) use Unicode escapes:

```
var goodQuotes = badQuotes.replace(/[\u2018\u2019]/g, "'");
```

That's for funny single quotes; the codes for double quotes are 201C and 201D.

*edit* — thus to completely replace *all* the fancy quotes:

```
var goodQuotes = badQuotes
  .replace(/[\u2018\u2019]/g, "'")
  .replace(/[\u201C\u201D]/g, '"');
```

Comment: >>> str.replace(/[\u2018\u2019]/g, "#");
Results in:
" “I don#t know what you mean by #glory,# ” Alice said."

Comment: Right.  Why did you put "#" in the replacement string? If you want to replace both sort of quotes, you'd need two calls to `.replace()`. I'll update the answer.

Comment: You can extend this script with the following, which replaces em dashes and ellipses that you get in text boxes when pasting from Word etc:    `.replace(/[\u2013\u2014]/g, '-')
   .replace(/[\u2026]/g, '...')`

Comment: spent three days staring a whole in my laptop trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't work because you're trying to replace the ASCII apostrophe (or single-quote) and quote characters with the empty string, when what's actually in your source string aren't ASCII characters.

```
str.replace(/[“”‘’]/g,'');
```

works.

Answer (score 1):

Combining [Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9401374/3357935) and [Wooble's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9401370/3357935) answers, if you want to replace the curly quotes with regular quotes:

```
str = str.replace(/[“”]/g, '"').replace(/[‘’]/g, "'");
```

So for example:

```js
str = '“I don’t know what you mean by ‘glory,’ ” Alice said.';
str = str.replace(/[“”]/g, '"').replace(/[‘’]/g, "'");
console.log(str)
```