# Removing quotation mark using javascript does not remove single quotation marks

Tags: javascript

Using a javascript to strip out some characters in a form is not removing the ’‘ all others are removed

The code I am using is

```
function stripIt(x){
x.value = x.value.replace(/[)’‘(&%<>?$-]/g,'');
};


so its the ’‘ that are not being removed
```

Thanks

Using the info from

You might need to use unicode: stackoverflow.com/questions/9401312/… –  sirrocco 41 mins ago

I sorted the problem with this

```
x.value = x.value.replace(/[\u2018\u2019]/g, "'");
x.value = x.value.replace(/[\u201C\u201D]/g, '"');
```

Thanks all for your input

Comment: Specifically smart quotes, or actual single quotes?

Comment: works for me in Chrome

Comment: Can't repro: https://jsfiddle.net/gyuwu2h6/ .

Comment: You might need to use unicode: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401312/how-to-replace-curly-quotation-marks-in-a-string-using-javascript