# Is single quote handled differently on IOS and Sierra?

Tags: javascript, ios, macos-sierra

Is a single quote (apostrophe) handled differently on IOS versus Sierra?  Is it a different character in Javascript.

I am attempting to strip single quotes in my search algorithm since it is occasionally reflected in the database with a quote and sometimes without.  For example:  search for "Keith's".  My current system works on macOS-sierra, but fails on iOS.

You can view the website here.  Type "keith's" into the search box.  It will work with your desktop, but fail with your iPhone or iPad.  Make sure you're searching within LCBO.

[http://brewskibooze.com](http://brewskibooze.com/?destination=liquor)

Currently, I simply use this line of code in javascript to strip out single quote.

searchString = replaceAll(searchString,"'","");

Answer (score 1):

I just answered my own question.  I needed to add this line.

str = str.replace(/[\u2018\u2019]/g, "")

Thanks goes to Pointy in his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401312/how-to-replace-curly-quotation-marks-in-a-string-using-javascript).