# How do I turn a JSON file into an arraylist

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to turn my JSON file into an arraylist that I can then access and use to display the information on the web page.

my html file

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
 if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(this.responseText))
}
};
 xmlhttp.open("GET", "PATIENT51.txt", true);
 xmlhttp.send();
```

my JSON file

```
{
“resourceType”:”RiskAssessment”,
“Notes”: [
{“date”: “05/13/2019”, “note”: “my notes”},
{“date”: “02/22/2018”, “note”: “cool”}
]
}
```

How do I access the `05/13/2019`, I’ve tried using

```
myObj.Notes[0].note;
```

But I get “undefined” as a result, I want to be able to make a table using the dates- each date will have a note associated with it.

Comment: The JSON says `Notes` not `note`. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Shouldn't be myObj.Notes[0].note ? :D

Comment: Yeah its that way in my code, just a typo when I wrote it here, sorry

Comment: I rolled it back to the edit before the quotes were edited in by @Intervalia because that might be the root of your problem why everything is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use balanced quotes or however they're called in json `“ and ”` are not valid JSON chatarters. use normal quotes. '"'

```js
JSON.parse('{ \
“resourceType”:”RiskAssessment”, \
“Notes”: [ \
{“date”: “05/13/2019”, “note”: “my notes”}, \
{“date”: “02/22/2018”, “note”: “cool”} \
] \
}');
```

Gives within chrome for me the expected error:

> VM18:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token “ in JSON at position 2
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at js:13

Use normal quotes `"`

Then when you analyze the outputted Object in console.log you see that the element where you wish to retrieve values from is called 'Notes' and not note. So you need to use `myObj.Notes[0].note` to access the variable you're interested in.

```js
myObj = JSON.parse('{ \
"resourceType":"RiskAssessment", \
"Notes": [ \
{"date": "05/13/2019", "note": "my notes"}, \
{"date": "02/22/2018", "note": "cool"} \
] \
}');
console.log(myObj);
console.log(myObj.Notes[0].note);
```

If you wish to replace the curly/balanced quotes in your code snippet by using the file you can use the solution from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9401374/1356107

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
 if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(this.responseText.replace(/[\u2018\u2019\u201C\u201D]/g, '"')));
}
};
 xmlhttp.open("GET", "PATIENT51.txt", true);
 xmlhttp.send();
```

but ideally you would have whatever generates PATIENTS1.txt use normal quotes instead of balanced quotes.

Comment: Is there any way to do this with a file rather than just parsing it directly? @Tschallacka

Comment: @jenna If it's because of the quotes you can do a string replace before parsing it.  `your_string.replace(/[\u2018\u2019\u201C\u201D]/g, '"');` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401312/how-to-replace-curly-quotation-marks-in-a-string-using-javascript

So in your example in your response handler it would be 
 `console.log(JSON.parse(this.responseText.replace(/[\u2018\u2019\u201C\u201D]/g, '"')))`

Comment: I still want to parse it I just want to be able to parse a file from an outside source

Comment: @jenna I modified my comment. You can use your code. See the last snippet in my comment

Comment: so I got an error JSON.parse Error:Invalid character at position:10 which is in the middle of the if statement @Tschallacka

Comment: @jenna The parse error is within the json file. Look at that line in the json file. It might be that you have more invalid characters in your JSON files. How are those generated? Are you able to modify the file you're reading from?