# How to use JSON data to create an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Okay so I want to be able to take a JSON file (external) and process it so that I can create an array that I can use to display the data.

JSON.parse() only works if I declare the JSON array then parse it, it does not work for external JSON data

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

  if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(this.responseText.replace(/[u2018\u2019\u201c\u201D]/g,'"')));

   document.getElementById("here").innerHTML =
        console.log(myObj.Cardionotes[0].note);
  }
};  xmlhttp.open("GET", "PATIENT51.txt", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
        };
```

I've used this question for help but I'm getting the same error- JSON.parse Error: Invalid character at position:3 (that's the middle of the if)
[How do I turn a JSON file into an arraylist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56691605/how-do-i-turn-a-json-file-into-an-arraylist)

Comment: You need to share your code.

Comment: You need to provide more detail about what it is you are doing and what the specific errors you are seeing are.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `fetch()` (or use a library like [umbrella](https://github.com/franciscop/umbrella) or [jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery)) instead of trying to use AJAX without a library, you will want to bang your head into a wall once you discover all the problems there are with different implementations across browsers...:

```js
const response = fetch('https://www.reddit.com/r/json.json')
    .then((data) => {
        // do your .replace(/[u2018\u2019\u201c\u201D]/g,'"') here, e.g.
        // data.replace(/[u2018\u2019\u201c\u201D]/g,'"').json();
        return data.json();
    })
    .then((json) => {
        console.log(json);
    })
    .catch(err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```