# Apostrophe is not getting accepted in our React input text component for Just iPhone alone

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, redux

So we have input text component which we are using it as a contact form where its working normally when we test it on Web/Desktop version. The issues occurs whenever we use test on iPhone its not accepting the the value. **eg; O'Connor..** or whatever that goes with apostrophe.. I have used the multiple encoding ways but it still no use.
Any help would be really appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not be related to your issue, but I discovered today that React Native's TextInput feature, on iOS, handles apostrophes and quotation marks in a strange way (which I have not observed with other punctuation). When you enter either character, it calls `onSelectionChange` twice before it calls `onChangeText`, which caused very strange behavior in a custom text input component. Possibly this is a result of some auto-formatting feature baked into iOS, and if so that might be part of your issue, even in a React web environment.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is about 10 months old but I actually just ran into a similar issue. I think this smart quotes issue.. IOS is changing the apostrophe to a right-single quote.

Try this `var goodQuotes = badQuotes.replace(/[\u2018\u2019]/g, "'");`

and for more information I got it from [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401312/how-to-replace-curly-quotation-marks-in-a-string-using-javascript#:%7E:text=var%20goodQuotes%20%3D%20badQuotes.replace(/%5B%5Cu2018%5Cu2019%5D/g%2C%20%22%27%22)%3B)